# Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, google-cloud-firestore, angular6

I am using Angular6 and trying to get the document content within this filter function. The very last line of my code snippet is giving me the error "Untyped function calls may not accept type arguments". Not sure why I'm getting this error... maybe it cannot be used within filter function...?

Constructor:

```
constructor(private afs : AngularFirestore, private authService : AuthService) { 
  //Get user collection on initialise
  this.userCollection = this.afs.collection('users');
}
```

Filtering:

```
this.userCollection = this.afs.collection<User>('users', ref => {
      console.log(ref);
      return ref
    })

    this.usersOnSearch = this.userCollection.valueChanges();

    this.usersOnSearch.flatMap(user => {
      return user.filter(function(value) {
        let subjectTrue : boolean = false;
        let levelTrue : boolean = false;
        let docID : string = value.user_subjects.id;
        let userLevelPriceDocument :  AngularFirestoreDocument<UserSubjects>;
        userLevelPriceDocument = this.afs.doc<UserSubjects>(`user_subjects/${docID}`);
      })
    });
```

Comment: If you remove <UserSubjects>, do you have the error? Can we have also you constructor ? And your component variable

Comment: If I remove <UserSubjects> I no longer get the error.Other info is updated.

Comment: You don't appear to be returning anything at all in the filter() function - should you not return a true/false to indicate whether a given user should be included in the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flatMap` signature expects a type of `Observable<T>` to be returned. In your case you are returning only `<T>` (in your case is `any` as this is control output). Try to wrap returned value with `Observable.of()`:

```
this.usersOnSearch.flatMap(user => {
  return Observable.of( user.filter(function(value) {
    let subjectTrue : boolean = false;
    let levelTrue : boolean = false;
    let docID : string = value.user_subjects.id;
    let userLevelPriceDocument :  AngularFirestoreDocument<UserSubjects>;
    userLevelPriceDocument = this.afs.doc<UserSubjects>(`user_subjects/${docID}`);
  })
  )
});
```

Comment: This did not work unfortunately. If I remove <UserSubjects> as mentioned by @Wandrille then it gets rid of the error

Comment: I think this is the correct approach, but should be "of" not "Observable.of" for Angular 6 / rxjs 6.